# How to add custom-logo/image in toolbar using vuetify

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to add image/custom logo in the toolbar using Vuetify.
I am using `v-toolbar` to create the navigation bar.

The image is not showing up. It shows the error of `[Vuetify] Image load failed
src: ../assets/mad_logo.png`

I tried using `<v-img>`
But it did not work.

This is how the navigation bar looks like

[image]

This is the code:

VuetifyTest.js

```
   <v-toolbar
    color="primary"
    >



    <v-toolbar-side-icon>
        <v-img src="../assets/mad_logo.png" />
    </v-toolbar-side-icon>  
    <v-toolbar-title class="black--text">Title</v-toolbar-title>

    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-avatar>
      <img
        src="../assets/static.jpeg"
        alt="John"
      >
    </v-avatar>


  </v-toolbar>


</template>

<script lang="js">
  export default  {
    name: 'profile',
    props: [],
    mounted() {

    },
    data() {
      return {

      }
    },
    methods: {

    },
    computed: {

    }
}
</script>

<style scoped >

</style>
```

This is the directory structure:

[image]

How do I attach the logo on the top left of the navigation bar and load the image correctly.

Any code changes would work.
Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

With `Vuetify 2` and above version, you can add a logo before your toolbar title like this:

```
<v-toolbar>
  <!-- Adjust the height to your needs, mine is 40 -->
  <img class="mr-3" :src="require('../assets/your_image.png')" height="40"/>
  <v-toolbar-title>Title</v-toolbar-title>
  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
  <v-toolbar-items>
    <v-btn text>Home</v-btn>
    <v-btn text>About</v-btn>
  </v-toolbar-items>
</v-toolbar>
```

Also, `<v-toolbar-side-icon>` is already `<v-app-bar-nav-icon>`

Comment: this is def the right answer for vuetify2 a toolbar image.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use :

```
<v-img :src="require('@/assets/mad_logo.png')" >
```

Comment: You can also try this if the above answer doesn't work- 

<v-img :src="require('../assets/mad_logo.png')" >

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using require the loader won't digest to render your actual page

So i prefered the code and enjoy!

```
     <v-toolbar-side-icon>
            <v-img class="mr-3" src="@/assets/logo.png" height="30px" width="40px"> 
            </v-img>
     </v-toolbar-side-icon>
```

Regards,

[Kamalesh Sivaraj](https://kamaleshsivaraj.now.sh/)!

Answer (score 0):

I have try to put this HTML `<img src="/assets/mad_logo.png" height="20px">` and it is appear to be ok on my toolbar.